# Programmatically adding an Exchange Online mailbox to Outlook

Tags: outlook-redemption

Does Redemption support adding an Exchange Online mailbox to Outlook? I know this can be done for a .pst using `NameSpace.AddStoreEx`, but can Redemption handle an Exchange Online store?

My goal is to turn off Outlook automapping and programmatically add Exchange Online mailboxes based on delegated permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Redemption exposes `RDOSession.Stores.AddDelegateExchangeMailBoxStore` - note that it needs to be able to retrieve the autodiscover XML of that mailbox. It needs to either be cached, or used alongside `RDOSession.LogonHostedExhangeMailbox` (which takes explicit credentials) or the parent `RDOSession` object must be used inside the outlook.exe address space (e.g. from a COM addin or Outlook VBA) - this way Redemption can intercept Outlook credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` or any other standard folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want to do.  I want Outlook to display the entire mailbox just as if it was manually added.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Understood. In that case Redemption can definitely help. I'll leave it there in case if anybody else wants separate folders, not a store.